# error python under help() - modules

Tags: python-2.7

I got this error when I try to see all modules using python:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

*$python - help() - modules*

```
WARNING: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK [gtk]
Segmentation fault
```

I need some help.

Comment: Think this needs reporting - http://bugs.python.org/

Comment: As I understand it, this is a potentially a problem with the packaged version of PyGTK.  Can you type entering `set_interactive(1)` to see if that resolves your issue?

Comment: I need more info about set_interactive...Can you send me a link how to use this ?